# Partitioning matrix in half and multiplying in parallel: local and remote

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix, parallel-processing

I have been working for my homework for a few days. I need to multiply two matrices using parallel processing technique.

I do the following as experimental:

1. I multiply the matrices on a single machine using single thread and calculate the duration
2. I multiply the matrices on a single machine using multithreading and calculate the duration
3. I divide the first matrix into two pieces horizontally in the half and multiply its half on my local computer and the remaining half on a remote computer.

--

```
double[][] A = new double[1000][1000];
double[][] B = new double[1000][1000];
double[][] C = new double[1000][1000];


double[][] A1 = new double[500][1000];
double[][] A2 = new double[500][1000];


double[][] C1 = new double[500][1000];
double[][] C2 = new double[500][1000];


C1 = multiplyLocal(A1, B);
C2 = multiplyRemote(mat2Str(A2,0,A2.length), mat2Str(B,0,B.length));
```

Because I could not succeed transferring double[][] arrays over web methods, I had to convert matrices to `String` for transferring to remote and convert back to `double[][]` array in multiplyRemote() method. After calculation I convert result to `String` and return to client then the client converts it to `double[][]` array again.

```
public static double[][] multiplyLocal(final double[][] blockA, final double[][] B) {

     final double[][] C1 = new double[blockA.length][blockA[0].length];

    final int nThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    final int blockSize = blockA.length / nThreads;
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[nThreads];

    for (int n = 0; n < nThreads; n++) {
        final int finalN = n;
        threads[n] = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final int beginIndex = finalN * blockSize;
                final int endIndex = (finalN == (nThreads - 1)) ? blockA.length : (finalN + 1) * blockSize;
                for (int i = beginIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < blockA.length; j++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < blockA[0].length; k++) {
                            C1[i][j] += blockA[i][k] * mB[k][j];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        threads[n].start();
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < nThreads; n++) {
        try {
            threads[n].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    return C1; 
}
```

This is the web method multiplyRemote

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "multiplyRemote")
public String multiplyRemote(final String blockA, final String B) {

    final double[][] mA = str2Mat(blockA);
    final double[][] mB = str2Mat(B);
    final double[][] C2 = new double[mA.length][mA[0].length];

    final int nThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    final int blockSize = mA.length / nThreads;
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[nThreads];

    for (int n = 0; n < nThreads; n++) {
        final int finalN = n;
        threads[n] = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final int beginIndex = finalN * blockSize;
                final int endIndex = (finalN == (nThreads - 1)) ? mA.length : (finalN + 1) * blockSize;
                for (int i = beginIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < mA.length; j++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < mA[0].length; k++) {
                            C2[i][j] += mA[i][k] * mB[k][j];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        threads[n].start();
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < nThreads; n++) {
        try {
            threads[n].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
    //mat2Str(double[][], startIndex, rowCount)   
    return mat2Str(C2, 0 , C2.length);
}
```

Yes, I was thinking that I was doing 3rd step in parallel. So I have noticed that it does not jump to next line without finishing `multiplyLocal()` process. I mean the remote computer waits idle until local finishes its job.

I need to send the half of the process to remote computer and calculate the other half on local until remote result returns.

How can I do that?

Comment: That depends on what you are doing in `multiplyLocal()`. Are you joing the threads inside that method?

Comment: @Thomas yes, I am joining threads in multiplyLocal() method.

Comment: That's the problem then: the main thread (I assume that's where you call both methods) will block until all the local threads return. As Maksym said, you need to either call `multiplyLocal()` in another thread or don't join and use a `Future` instead.

Comment: I manage a Data Parallel project on SourceForge that does matrix multiply as a built-in-function locally and remotely (using RMI.) You can see how it works and just copy the code or whatever you want. http://sourceforge.net/projects/tymeacdse/?source=navbar

Answer (score 0):

You should run multiplyLocal(A1, B) in another thread. https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6